# IEEE submission vs ArXiv Version with missing IEEE-statement

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, ieee, preprint, policy

I've just got and corrected my revised paper. I submitted the revision to IEEE and I uploaded a newer version to ArXiv. BUT I made a mistake and the IEEE-disclaimer statement was regretfully missing on the ArXiv version and I did not notice it. (the older versions DO have the IEEE-disclaimer.)

Now, I get the feedback from the Editorial Office that it is a quite serious problem and I should add the statement to my paper.

The question is:
Do you think that it is enough if I update the paper on ArXiv? Won't the fact be a problem that the older version (without IEEE-disclaimer) is still available? Or should I contact the ArXiv-support team? Could they make an exception?

Yes, I know that this is a stupid mistake, but it would be really bad if the IEEE Transaction wouldn't publish the work because it is really important to my PhD...

Comment: You are unlikely to be the first person to make such a mistake. So, go take care of it as IEEE requested.

Comment: Thanks, @JonCuster? So are you suggesting that I should contact ArXiv to change my last version? Our I should simply add the newer, corrected version?

Comment: Replace, per the [help documentation](https://arxiv.org/help/replace#minorchanges). If you believe your situation warrants an exception, you should contact [arXiv's helpdesk](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you!
Indeed, I was not the first person. Replacing the pdf was enough for the editor and finally our work got published :)